# Excel 2010: How would I use information within columns as Row headings?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have information that is in this format (space delimited):

```
CustomerNbr Employee        Employee      Employee      Employee
1234567890  Martha.Stewart  Tom.Brady     Master.Chief  Bart.Simpson
2345678901  Martha.Stewart  Tom.Brady     Bart.Simpson  
3456789012  Martha.Stewart  Master.Chief        
4567890123  Tom.Brady       Bart.Simpson        
5678901234  Tom.Brady       Bart.Simpson        
6789012345  Tom.Brady           
7890123456  Martha.Stewart          
8901234567  Master.Chief            
9012345678  Master.Chief
```

I need it to be in this format (space delimited):

```
Employee       CustomerNbr    CustomerNbr     CustomerNbr   CustomerNbr  CustomerNbr
Martha.Stewart 1234567890     2345678901     3456789012     7890123456  
Tom.Brady      1234567890     2345678901     4567890123     5678901234   6789012345
Master.Chief   1234567890     3456789012     8901234567     9012345678  
Bart.Simpson   1234567890     2345678901     4567890123     5678901234
```

Is there a way to do this?  I have searched to no avail thus far.  The idea is to flip the relationship between them, but I cannot find a way through excel and don't know enough about macros to do something this complex.

The closest I found was this: [Return column header based on row header and cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11458744/return-column-header-based-on-row-header-and-cell-value)

Comment: Do you have a list of unique customers available?

Comment: Yes, I do have that information in a column in a separate worksheet in the same workbook.  I also have a list on unique Employees in another worksheet the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A3:A11`: the initial table.

`A15`: name of the employee ("Martha.Stuart")

`B15`: Array formula (insert pressing Ctrl-Shift-Enter in a formula window; curled brackets will be inserted by Excel, not by a user):

```
{=LEFT(OFFSET($A$1;SMALL(IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(" "&$A15&" ";$A$3:$A$11)));ROW($A$3:$A$11);IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(" "&$A15;$A$3:$A$11))=FALSE;IF(SEARCH(" "&$A15;$A$3:$A$11)=LEN($A$3:$A$11)-LEN($A15);ROW($A$3:$A$11);65000)));B$14)-1;0);10)}
```

Example spreadsheet: http://www.bumpclub.ee/~jyri_r/Excel/Customer_number_transposition.xls

Comment: This is almost perfect.  Using your example spreadsheet I almost get the correct answer, but whenever I change the range <$A$3:$A$11> to try and make it fit my data <$A$3:$A$2350>, the formula no longer works.  I can move and extend the results area successfully, but no matter how I change the range reference within the formula it results in #REF.

Comment: It seems to choke when I fill in the reference with the range.  When doing the step by step it gets a result of #VALUE! for the range.

Comment: There's no need to replace ranges in formulae, if the number of filled rows is less than in formulae. If replacement is needed, running Ctrl-H  on formulae is the easiest way.

Comment: One more thing: after editing a formula, you should insert it with Ctrl-Shift-Enter in a formula window. Simple Enter will give an error.

Comment: Ahh, I think that was my problem.  Now I know!!  It worked like a charm and I thank you very much!!